# Shutting off power with a non-system r/w ext4 volume mounted

Tags: raspberry-pi, ext4, fstab, readonly

I'm running Raspbian off a read-only ext4 volume. I also have a read/write usb flash volume (ext4, sync) mounted via fstab that runs a simple application that is expected to write occasionally. While I'm not worried about the root partition (it is read-only), I'm concerned about the rw partition.

Is it safe to cut off the power, if I assume that the volume isn't being written to at the moment and there's no stdout/stderr redirection?

Will shutting off power result in a system integrity check upon reboot?

If there is stdout/stderr redirection (to a file on the rw partition) on an open process, does that mean that the file is kept open as long as the process is running?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to cut off the power, if I assume that the volume isn't being written to at the moment and there's no stdout/stderr redirection? // If there is stdout/stderr redirection (to a file on the rw partition) on an open process, does that mean that the file is kept open as long as the process is running?

You are mistaken on how Linux handles pending buffers. This isn't related to open files at all. Buffers may be pending when the process which created them is long gone. The only way to ensure all data is on the media is umounting or remounting read-only the filesystem.

> Will shutting off power result in a system integrity check upon reboot?

A filesystem not properly umounted/remounted as read-only will be detected as *dirty* on next mount. Because this is ext4, mounting such a dirty filesystem is possible – the driver will stick to the journal then. The last changes before power-off are lost.

Comment: The rw partition is mounted with 'sync', so there should be nothing buffered. Odds of something being written at any particular point are fairly low.

Comment: You should reconsider that. My experience with sync-mounting flash media is long and disastrous. Much too many erases. The remaining erase cycles melt faster than fat in the sun.